# Overcommitting memory on an Ubuntu Server 9.10 running on VMWare Fusion 3.0 (osx)

Tags: mac-osx, memory, vmware-fusion

I can't set the **overcommit_memory** from inside the shell:

```
root@ubuntu:~# /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory = 1
-bash: /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory: Permission denied
```

Also I tried putting that line in /etc/**sysctl.conf** and rebooting the vm but it's not working.

Someone have some clues? I couldn't find anything searching in google.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen differently that is not?  I suspect this setting is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Settings in /proc/sys are virtual files.  To change them, you need to write to them like you would any other file, like so:

```
echo 1 >/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

The command you tried is to run `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` as an executable, which of course is impossible.  The "Permission denied" you're getting is because that file is not set as executable, not because you can't change it.

You can see the current setting by reading the file:

```
cat /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you jeff, i tried:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

but:

```
-bash: echo: write error: Operation not permitted
```

the problem was that the ability to write the file was 'locked' by the VM server so I had to ask the sysadmin to enable it

on an unix box at home where i installed VMWare server i tried it and it worked either mine and your solution.

Answer (score -1):

First you should use the command `cat /proc/mounts`.

If the mount point `/proc` was mounted in read only mode, then you must remount it.

Try remounting with the command `mount -o remount,rw /proc`.

After remount, try using the `echo` command again.